# Unable to stop tomcat6 when using jmx port options

Tags: centos, tomcat6

We have tomcat6 running in two different environments, both running CentOS 6.6 and OpenJDK 1.7.  In one environment, I'm not able to stop tomcat6 when issuing

```
service tomcat6 stop
```

In the environment that this is failing, the only difference is that there are some additional options:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=**8081**
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.19.13.211
```

When stopping, the following errors are recorded in catalina.out:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory (errno = 1).
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory (errno = 1).
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory (errno = 1).
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: **8081**; nested exception is: 
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

It looks like the jmx port is what is causing this issue, but without removing it altogether, is there a way to get tomcat6 to stop gracefully?

### UPDATE 1

The link mentioned in my comment led me to a [blog post](http://blog.mafr.de/2011/03/12/enabling-jmx-acces-on-tomcat/) that I followed.  I created the /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/setenv.sh file, and made it readable with the following contents:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8081 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.19.13.211"
```

However, when starting tomcat6 up, the jmx options are not being included. Any suggestions?

Comment: sort out the jmx port asin change the 8081 to something else

Comment: A bit more searching yielded [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199630/cant-stop-tomcat-normally-when-i-configure-jmxremote). Will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

Using some information from [this page](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/) I added the following to the tomcat6 startup script (which in my case was `/usr/sbin/tomcat6`):

```
if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
fi
```

The final contents of my `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/setenv.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8081 \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \ 
                      -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.19.13.211"
```

Now I can start tomcat6 successfully with the jmx options:

```
[root@hrndvsoi-dev1-ucsync01 tomcat6]# service tomcat6 start
Starting tomcat6:                                          [  OK  ]

[root@hrndvsoi-dev1-ucsync01 tomcat6]# ps -ef | grep tomc | grep -v grep | sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | grep -e jmx -e rmi
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8081
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.19.13.211
```

And I can stop tomcat6 without any errors:

```
[root@hrndvsoi-dev1-ucsync01 tomcat6]# service tomcat6 stop
Stopping tomcat6:                                          [  OK  ]
```

Hope this helps someone else.